# typedef equivalent for int

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

If I have a template container, I can use a `typedef` to let me lookup the type at compile time:

```
template <typename T>
struct MyList {
    typedef T Type;
    T get_front() const;
    // ...
};

MyList<char> char_list;
MyList<char>::Type front = char_list.get_front();
```

In this case you could declare `char front = char_list.get_front();` instead, but sometimes this can be useful (e.g. template classes that contain other template classes).

In my case, the template doesn't specify a typename, but instead specifies an int (actually a `std::size_t`):

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct MyClass {
    // ...
};
```

Is there an equivalent of a typedef that I can declare inside the class that will allow me to get the value N outside of the class? Is this an appropriate place to use a static constant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual approach on modern compilers is:

```
static const std::size_t value = N;
```

Note that this will raise *undefined-behavior* if someone tries to take its address. This often means that the address of `value` could result in different locations for different translation units, but its *undefined-behavior* nevertheless.

Another approach usually used on older compilers, and which does not leave the door of *undefined-behavior* open, is emulation via `enums`:

```
enum { value = N };
```

*Boost.Config* offers the `BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT` macro which will resolve to one or the other of the described approaches, based on compiler conformance. Its usage is:

```
BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT( std::size_t, value = N );
```

It's reference can be found at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.boost_helper_macros

Comment: Great answer-- since this is only inside in-house code (not accessible) I think the static const should be fine.

Comment: @Oliver: Just make sure that you never do `&value`, which could happen implicitly if you use `value` as an argument to a function taking a const reference parameter.

Comment: "modern compilers" — how modern does it need to be?